# Class's method doesn't see the global variables

Tags: python

I have a class:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.USB


def setPort(self, text):         
    if text == 'ttyUSB0':
        USB = serial.Serial(
                            port='/dev/ttyUSB0',\
                            baudrate=9600,\
                            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
                            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
                            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
                            writeTimeout=0)
```

I want to use self.USB variable as a global variable in a few methods in this class.

```
def refreshTIME(dummy):
        dummy.USB.write('3')
```

I got an error:

```
self.USB
AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'USB'
```

Shouldn't it be a global variable and visible in every methods in this class?

Comment: Why is there ``self`` in the definition of ``set()`` . It is a strong convention that this name is used to define method. Writing this, you induce the idea that ``set()`` should be a method, but it's indented outside the class. So what ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use a global variable here. In general, global variables are discouraged because they lead to messy spaghetti code.

In your `__init__` method you're trying to *access* the instance variable `USB`. It doesn't exist at that point so you have to set it:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.USB = None # sets the variable
        self.USB        # accesses the variable
```

Also your code for `setPort` sets the value for the *local* variable `USB` not for the *instance* variable. You can use `self.USB` to do that:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    # ... rest of class ...

    def setPort(self, text):         
        if text == 'ttyUSB0':
            self.USB = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
                                     baudrate=9600,
                                     parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                                     stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                                     bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                                     writeTimeout=0)
```

*Note:* You also don't need the `\` at the end of the lines.

Finally you should be able to access the USB instance variable:

```
def refreshTIME(dummy):
    dummy.USB.write('3')

myWindow = Window()
refreshTIME(myWindow)
```

You should also consider putting the `refreshTIME` function into the `Window` class as a method.

Comment: ``self.USB`` alone in the definition of a function means nothing

Comment: @eyquem it isn't a function, it's a method, I updated the code example to make that more clear

Comment: There are \ simbols, somehow it disappeared when copied here. refreshTIME should work when a QPushButton is pushed. That's why I wanted all of the stuffs ( button, the method, which happens at every click) put in a class. Unforunately the problem is still here.

Comment: @erbal your code doesn't indicate what you're doing with the refreshTIME method and we're trying to solve one problem at a time which is that you couldn't refer to the variable (because it wasn't defined). if there's a new problem, please update the question

Comment: @omouse If you define ``self.USB = None`` the attribute with name ``USB`` isn't a method. If it were a method, it should be called with ``self.USB()``, anyway. Your code remains mysterious for me.

Comment: @omouse See my comment to the OP's question about the presence of self in,  and indentation of , ``set()``. In your coode, you make ``set()`` a method of ``Window()``. It isn't clear if it is the case or not. I smell the problem as another one who is miserably asked.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/956k9kq4fkia3ll/GUI.py here's the full code. I just want if I make a serial connection in the setPort, then the USB variable be visible to all of the class's methods.

Answer (score 0):

define self.USB while defining the function **init**.

```
self.USB = "something"
```

Comment: It says: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: you need to do a full code example (that line of code + the surrounding __init__ method).

Answer (score 0):

You should add this in the `__init__` method:

```
self.USB = None    # or give it another initial value
```

Then, when you want to use this variable in other methods of the class, the usage is like this:

```
self.USB = xxx     # some opertations
```

Comment: It says: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @erbal, where does this exception happends, at the line of the `setPort` function?

Comment: It seems like USB doesn'z get a new value in setPort, and that's why I get this error now: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: @erbal, can you typeset your code? It's not clear and puzzling.

Answer (score -1):

I have this code which is a very weird manner to play with namespaces.
Is it something like that you want to do ?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        if x is None:
            self.name = 'unknown'
        else:
            self.name = x

print 'class A created'
print 'y' in dir()

class Window(A):
    def __init__(self,name, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.name = name
        self.USB = ['SOME_thing']
        y = self.USB
        global y

print 'clas Window created'
print 'y' in dir()

w = Window('Try1')

print '\ninstance w created'
print 'y' in dir()

def refreshTIME(dummy=y):
    dummy[0] = dummy[0].lower()

print 'function refreshTime created'
print 'y' in dir()

print '------------'
print 'w.name ==',w.name
print 'w.USB ==',w.USB
print 'y ==',y
refreshTIME()
print 'w.name ==',w.name
print 'w.USB ==',w.USB
print 'y ==',y
```

result

```
class A created
False
clas Window created
False

instance w created
True
function refreshTime created
True
------------
w.name == Try1
w.USB == ['SOME_thing']
y == ['SOME_thing']
w.name == Try1
w.USB == ['some_thing']
y == ['some_thing']
```

Comment: I'd like to know what is critcable in my answer instead of being silently downvoted. The OP's question looks awkard to me, so my answer is weird too. It doesn't mean that I support this way of coding.